# $S\neq\varnothing$ $ a-b\in S, ab\in S \forall a, b \in S \Leftrightarrow S$ is a subring of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm reading in the book "basic abstract algebra"  by **P. B Bhattacharya, S. R. Nagpaul, S. K. Jain** and I'm trying to understand the proof in the book (page 169).

The book says that $a-b \in S \quad \forall a,b\in R  $ implies that $(S,+)$ is an additive subgroup of $(R,+)$.

I do not understand why this is the case, can you tell me why?

And does it also imply that $(S,+)$ is abelian?

Comment: In general, a nonempty subset $X$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup if $ab^{-1}\in X$ for all $a,b\in X$. Written additively, this is just "$a-b$". It does not imply or require $G$ or $X$ to be abelian.

Comment: Which book is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean for all $a,b \in R$, not for the product in $R$ I assume...
What are the axioms of a subgroup?
You should check them one by one, for example: Can you write $ 0 = a-b$ for some $a,b \in R?$

And if $(R,+)$ is abelian, than also every subgroup is, yes.

Comment: Wops yeah, it was supposed to say $a, b \in R$

Answer (score 1):

The condition $a-b \in S$ for all $a,b\in S$ alone is not sufficient.
You also need the condition $S \neq \emptyset $.
Then you can proceed to check the subgroup axioms:
Since $S \neq \emptyset$, there is an $a \in S$, and by the first condition we get $0=a-a \in S$. Now that we have established that $0 \in S$, we can show that for each element $a \in S$, its inverse lies in $S$: since $0,a \in S$, by the first condition we get $-a=0-a \in S$ etc.